# Поиск и возврат значения по ID (for json)

Tags: javascript, json

Что я делаю не так?
У меня есть json файл. Вывод сделал, работает адекватно. Пытаюсь сделать функцию, которая ищет ID сервера и если они совпадают с тем, что я указал, то выводим название этого сервера. А в итоге, код перебирает все ID, и если есть совпадение, то он устанавливает название сервера и выводит его дальше везде.
Проще говоря, надо вывести название сервера по установленному мной ID один раз. Тобишь функция при выводе будет просто заменять ID на название. Воть...
Написал фигню, но может кто поймет :)

Js:

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo $servers; ?>', function(data) {
     $(data.data).each(function(index, item) {
         for (var i = 0; i < item.servers.length; i++) {
             if(30 === item.servers[i].id) { // 30 - ID сервера
                 var servername = item.servers[i].hostname;
             }
             alert(servername);
             //return servername;
         }
     });
});
```

Json (пример вывода json, он выводится через echo php):

```js
...
"data":{
    "servers":[
    {
         "id":30,
         "hostname":"#SERVER xD 1"
    },
    {
         "id":41,
         "hostname":"#SERVER xD 2"
    },
},
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var json = {
  data : {
    servers:[
      {
        "id":30,
        "hostname":"#SERVER xD 1"
      },
      {
        "id":41,
        "hostname":"#SERVER xD 2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

$(json.data.servers).each(function(index, server) {
  if(server.id == 30){
     console.log(server.hostname);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Красота. Спасибо!