# getJSON внутри функции

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Продолжение данной темы [Поиск и возврат значения по ID (for json)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898905/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id-for-json)
Возникла другая проблема. Изначально планировалось использовать данный код, как функцию замены ID на Name.
Почитал, что функция getJSON не может так работать, т.к. async = true.

Как мне сделать данную функцию рабочей. Перерыл весь Стак и Гугл, ответы нашел, но не получилось их реализовать.

```
function fachang(sid) {
    $.getJSON('<?php echo $servers; ?>', function(data) {
        $(data.data.servers).each(function(index, server) {
            if(server.id == sid){ //sid = id сервера
                return server.hostname;
            }
        });   
    });
}

alert(fachang(30)); // хотелось бы тут ответ - #SERVER xD 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var json = {
  data : {
    servers:[
      {
        "id":30,
        "hostname":"#SERVER xD 1"
      },
      {
        "id":41,
        "hostname":"#SERVER xD 2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

function fachang(sid, callback) {
    $(json.data.servers).each(function(index, server) {
      if(server.id == sid){ //sid = id сервера
        if(callback){
          callback(server.hostname);
        }
      }
    });   
}

fachang(30, function(result) {
 alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

для того чтобы получить информацию от `async` функций, необходимо использовать `callback` или `promice`. Так же можно посмотреть в сторону `async/await`

Comment: Пробовал такой вариант, но что-то упустил) Все супер) Опять же благодарю)

Comment: почему-то когда я использую эту функцию при render в datatable, таблица 100 лет грузится и на выходе пустые ячейки... Хм..

Comment: @Xhonor на словах мало понятно) код бы увидеть, может чем и помог

Comment: как-то так - https://jsfiddle.net/xhonor/72bu10zy/

Comment: @Xhonor у вас есть телеграмм любой месанджер, попробую помочь